# VS Code SSH-Remote to Rapberry Pi says: The VS Code Server failed to start

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm trying to connect to my Rapberry Pi running Raspbian (september 2019 version) using the Remote Development extension in VS code ([see here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)). My OpenSSH is working correctly as well as my key based authentication (cmd lets me connect with `pi@192.168.2.6` without providing the password).

My ssh config file looks as follows:

```
Host 192.168.2.6
HostName 192.168.2.6
User pi
IdentityFile C:/Users/ttimo/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When connecting to the host in VS Code I get the following error:

```
   [15:34:22.437] "install" terminal command done
   [15:34:22.439] Install terminal quit with output: 683ac00a76dd##32##
   [15:34:22.439] Received install output: 683ac00a76dd##32##
   [15:34:22.440] Resolver error: The VS Code Server failed to start
   [15:34:22.447] ------
```

I tried deleting the .vscode folder on my RPi but this did not work.

Thanks in advance